# Redis Multi-Set With a TTL

Tags: redis, key-value-store, ttl

In redis there is a `SETEX` command that allows me to set a key that expires, is there a multi-set version of this command that also has a TTL?

both `MSET` and `MSETNX` commands do not have such an option.

Comment: I mean.. one would wonder how this still doesn't exist in 2018.

Comment: And another year passed, wondering in 2019 too :(

Comment: and in 2020 too..

Comment: 2021 sais hi...

Comment: 2021 in (almost) March says hello as well.

Comment: 2021 in (almost) October says hello

Comment: They're running out of 2021....

Comment: In 2022 the question is still relevant.

Comment: 2023 says "oh boy, not yet"

Comment: 2024 be like :'(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was also looking for this kind of operation. I didn't find anything, so I did it with MULTI/EXEC:

```
MULTI
expire key1
expire key2
expire key3
EXEC
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing too.

Comment: it may be very slow, how to execute on java

Answer (score 9):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/502) for it back to 2012. For people who are wondering why they're not implement it.

> Unfortunately, we're not going to add more commands that can work on multiple keys because they are inherently difficult to distribute. Instead, explicitly calling EXPIRE for every key you want to expire is much easier to distribute (you can route every command to a different server if needed). If you want to EXPIRE keys atomically, you can wrap multiple calls in a MULTI/EXEC block.

---

BTW, if the [transaction](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) is not required, try using [pipeline](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) instead of `MULTI/EXEC` for [better performance](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining#it39s-not-just-a-matter-of-rtt).

> Pipelining is not just a way to reduce the latency cost associated with the round trip time, it actually greatly improves the number of operations you can perform per second in a given Redis server.

Answer (score 1):

As of Aug 2022, this action is not possible and probably will never be as mentioned in the comments here.
I have found a good solution (in my opinion) which is the fastest I've found.
My solution was using `hmset` for storing the keys, and afterwards using `expire` on the hash key.
This will set the ttl for the hash and therefore for all the keys in it.

This solution isn't perfect! But considering the other solutions and the lack of options with mset, this is a solid solution which helped me solve this problem.

Comment: We had similar approach, but the issue is, the action is not atomic, and under high load we had edge cases where we set the keys but for some reason they did not got TTL, which ended up in infite keys

Answer (score 0):

```
EVAL "<multi_ttl_script>" N key1 key2 ... value1 ttl1 value2 ttl2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

That's sad we cant set expire with mset, ahead a solution for who is working with nodejs and redis lib:

```
// expires the key at next mid-night
let now = moment()
let endOfDay = moment().endOf('day')
let timeToLiveInSeconds = endOfDay.diff(now, 'seconds')

redisClient.expire(keyName, timeToLiveInSeconds)
```

I hope it helps

Comment: This is a question about Redis, not about Node. I think nearly everyone that lands on this page knows the EXPIRE command exists: https://redis.io/commands/expire